# Returning VALUE or NULL in Azure Cosmos DB subquery

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The structure of the `Person` document I store in Azure Cosmos DB looks like this:

```
{
   "id": "some-id",
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "emails": [
      {
         "id": "email1",
         "email": "test@testsite.com",
         "isPrimary": true
      },
      {
         "id": "email2",
         "email": "test2@testsite.com",
         "isPrimary": false
      }
   ]
},
{
   "id": "some-other-id",
   "firstName": "Jane",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "emails": []
}
```

I'm trying to return the basic info of a person, including his/her primary email if they have one and `NULL` for email if there isn't a primary email.

This is the `SQL` statement I'm using but it's not returning Jane Doe at all because "I think" the `JOIN` is making the email required data.

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, email
FROM c JOIN (SELECT e.email FROM e IN c.emails WHERE e.isPrimary = true) AS email
```

I also tried the following but that doesn't Jane Doe at all.

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, e.email
FROM c JOIN e IN c.emails
WHERE e.isPrimary = true
```

I thought the following worked but that also seems to filter out some documents where there's an email but not a primary one.

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, e.email
FROM c JOIN e IN c.emails
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(c.emails) = 0 OR e.isPrimary = true
```

Just to reiterate the requirements: I want ALL persons. If the person has one or more emails and one is the primary one, I want to include only the primary email in the result. If the person doesn't have any emails or has emails but not a primary one, I still want the person in the results but email should be `NULL` for that particular person.

It's easy to do a `SELECT * FROM c` but I only want to get the primary email if the person has one or a `NULL` if they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT c.firstName, c.lastName,
ARRAY(SELECT VALUE e.email FROM e in c.emails WHERE e.isPrimary = true or ARRAY_LENGTH(c.emails) = 0) as email
FROM c

Comment: Surprisingly straightforward! Thank you!